# Combine ntile() together with collect_set() in window function pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate quartiles using F.ntile and trying to make it work together with F.collect_set as I need to include unique values only. Is it possible? I have tried somehting like below but didnt work.

```
df.withColumn("Quartile", F.ntile(4)(F.collect_set("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("col3", "col2").orderBy('col4'))
```

I feel like the below will work but I need to pass '4' as an argument to F.ntile(4):

```
df.withColumn("Quartile", F.ntile((F.collect_set("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("col3", "col2").orderBy('col4'))))
```

This is a basic view of how my df looks like:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+
|     id      |  group1   |   group2   |    date      |   score  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+
| 58172A0396  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-05   |     8    | 
| 58172A0396  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-06   |     8    |         
| 46C5Y00693  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-07   |    14    |         
| 46C5Y00693  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-08   |    14    |         
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-05   |    16    |         
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-06   |    16    |         
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-07   |    16    |         
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-08   |    16    |         
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-09   |    16    |         
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-10   |    16    |         
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

I want to group score column values into quartiles but based on unique id. Df contains multiple group1 and group2 values.
Expected output:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------+
|     id      |  group1   |   group2   |    date      |   score  |Quartile |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------+
| 58172A0396  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-05   |     8    |    1    |
| 58172A0396  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-06   |     8    |    1    |
| 46C5Y00693  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-07   |    14    |    3    |
| 46C5Y00693  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-08   |    14    |    3    |
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-05   |    16    |    4    |
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-06   |    16    |    4    |
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-07   |    16    |    4    |
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-08   |    16    |    4    |
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-09   |    16    |    4    |
| 1737K7008F  |     A     |     B1     | 2018-01-10   |    16    |    4    |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: `ntile(4)` will create quartiles based on the ordered column values within the window, and will not support arrays/lists. would you be able to take a distinct of the partition and order columns then create the quartiles? you'll need to join the quartile values in that case. *it's certainly not optimal for huge datasets.*

Comment: I have edited my post to show an example df. What I tried recently was to create another df where I get rid of columns like date and then run .distinct() on entire df. I could then calculate quartile and join the 2 dfs. However it looks like running .distinct() on entire df is pretty slow and my dataset has around 200k rows so I do care about performance and thought there is a better way.

Comment: you can try to use the method in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would use of an UDF work for you? We can use `numpy.quantile` to calculate the quantile values. Here's an example with the approach.

```
# input dataframe creation
data_ls = [(int(np.ceil(i/10)), random.randint(1, 100)) for i in range(1, 101)]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'val'])

# +---+---+
# | id|val|
# +---+---+
# |  1| 68|
# |  1| 92|
# |  1| 41|
# |  1| 86|
# |  1| 34|
# +---+---+
# only showing top 5 rows
```

Create UDF that uses `numpy.quantile` to calculate the Q1, Q2, Q3 values for a given list of values.

```
def getQuartileVals(val_list):
    import numpy as np

    q1_q2_q3 = np.quantile(val_list, [0.25, 0.5, 0.75])

    return [float(k) for k in q1_q2_q3]

getQuartileVals_udf = func.udf(getQuartileVals, ArrayType(FloatType()))
```

Use `collect_set` to create array of unique values for each partition and use the UDF to get the q values.

```
quartile_val_sdf = data_sdf. \
    groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.collect_set('val').alias('unique_vals')). \
    withColumn('q1_q2_q3_uvals', getQuartileVals_udf('unique_vals')). \
    drop('unique_vals')
```

Join the q values to the original dataframe for quartile creation.

```
data_sdf. \
    join(func.broadcast(quartile_val_sdf), 'id', 'left'). \
    withColumn('quartiles',
               func.when(func.col('val') <= func.col('q1_q2_q3_uvals')[0], func.lit(1)).
               when((func.col('val') > func.col('q1_q2_q3_uvals')[0]) & (func.col('val') <= func.col('q1_q2_q3_uvals')[1]), func.lit(2)).
               when((func.col('val') > func.col('q1_q2_q3_uvals')[1]) & (func.col('val') <= func.col('q1_q2_q3_uvals')[2]), func.lit(3)).
               when(func.col('val') > func.col('q1_q2_q3_uvals')[2], func.lit(4))
               ). \
    orderBy('id', 'quartiles', 'val'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+-------------------+---------+
# |id |val|q1_q2_q3_uvals     |quartiles|
# +---+---+-------------------+---------+
# |1  |8  |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|1        |
# |1  |17 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|1        |
# |1  |27 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|1        |
# |1  |34 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|2        |
# |1  |41 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|2        |
# |1  |49 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|3        |
# |1  |68 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|3        |
# |1  |86 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|4        |
# |1  |92 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|4        |
# |1  |98 |[28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|4        |
# |2  |13 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |1        |
# |2  |13 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |1        |
# |2  |54 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |1        |
# |2  |56 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |1        |
# |2  |67 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |2        |
# |2  |73 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |2        |
# |2  |91 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |3        |
# |2  |92 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |3        |
# |2  |95 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |4        |
# |2  |98 |[56.0, 73.0, 92.0] |4        |
# +---+---+-------------------+---------+
# only showing top 20 rows
```

---

q values using unique list of values and all values are quite different.

```
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.collect_set('val').alias('unique_vals'),
        func.collect_list('val').alias('all_vals')
        ). \
    withColumn('list_set_same', func.size('unique_vals') == func.size('all_vals')). \
    withColumn('q1_q2_q3_uvals', getQuartileVals_udf('unique_vals')). \
    withColumn('q1_q2_q3_avals', getQuartileVals_udf('all_vals')). \
    orderBy('id'). \
    show()

# +---+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# | id|         unique_vals|            all_vals|list_set_same|      q1_q2_q3_uvals|      q1_q2_q3_avals|
# +---+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# |  1|[41, 27, 34, 49, ...|[68, 92, 41, 86, ...|         true| [28.75, 45.0, 81.5]| [28.75, 45.0, 81.5]|
# |  2|[67, 13, 56, 54, ...|[95, 67, 98, 13, ...|        false|  [56.0, 73.0, 92.0]| [54.5, 70.0, 91.75]|
# |  3|[81, 52, 46, 82, ...|[73, 87, 91, 46, ...|        false|  [52.0, 77.0, 82.0]|[57.25, 79.0, 85.75]|
# |  4|[17, 86, 53, 42, ...|[4, 80, 80, 80, 4...|        false|[13.75, 47.5, 71.75]| [23.25, 61.0, 80.0]|
# |  5|[33, 99, 34, 49, ...|[99, 33, 47, 64, ...|        false|  [47.0, 64.0, 86.0]|  [47.5, 73.0, 86.0]|
# |  6|[15, 78, 19, 5, 2...|[19, 24, 15, 61, ...|         true|[19.25, 33.0, 73.75]|[19.25, 33.0, 73.75]|
# |  7|[70, 68, 6, 25, 1...|[11, 29, 25, 68, ...|        false|  [14.0, 26.0, 44.0]| [16.75, 27.5, 62.0]|
# |  8|[45, 34, 16, 5, 7...|[55, 10, 18, 34, ...|         true|  [16.5, 28.5, 46.5]|  [16.5, 28.5, 46.5]|
# |  9|[84, 12, 45, 78, ...|[57, 84, 17, 12, ...|         true|  [23.0, 51.0, 63.0]|  [23.0, 51.0, 63.0]|
# | 10|[51, 30, 45, 48, ...|[45, 83, 23, 30, ...|         true|[38.75, 46.5, 54.75]|[38.75, 46.5, 54.75]|
# +---+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

If you're using spark 3.1+, and want q values for all values within a column, you could look into the [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark-sql-functions-percentile-approx) function. The values won't match with `numpy` or `scipy` as this generates an approximate value.